# DateDiff for one column of Dates

Tags: excel, vba, datediff

Can I have help with this one, I am looking for work out the date difference of dates in one column like this,

[image]

Obviously I have tried a for loop but its never that easy, can anyone help :)

Comment: The date difference compared to what? The one above? The one below? The current date? Show what you have tried so far

Comment: It would be the one bellow tom, Its the column going down so would like the date diff in days to the right :)

Comment: You can just subtract one from the other in an Excel formula to get what you want. No need for anything fancy

Comment: But I would prefer to use VBA and say a for loop, I dont like using both at the same time :( is that strange

Comment: Well enjoy writing it. Yes it is strange. Excels inbuilt functionality is far more efficient then vba. You're putting performance overhangs on your cpu by finding it 'strange'. Excel was also never designed to be one or the other.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a formula i can use then, datediff doesnt seem to be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to achieve this with VBA, assuming your dates are in range A2:A6, try something like this...

```
Sub DateDif()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr - 1
    If IsDate(Cells(i, 1)) And IsDate(Cells(i + 1, 1)) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = DateDiff("d", Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1))
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Or try it like this which is easy to tweak...

```
Sub DateDif()
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    If IsDate(Cell) And IsDate(Cell.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = DateDiff("d", Cell, Cell.Offset(1, 0))
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry they are not they are in cells B10 downwards :)

Comment: No issues. I have added another approach which is easy for you to tweak.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i was looking to do, as im sure you can understand this was complicated for a beginner,Thank you bro

Answer (score 1):

If your Dates are all in Column `A` put in Column `B` `A3-A2` and drag down all cells (except last one) that have dates

[image]